# Show a url on a custom maps pin in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms I'm using the google maps plugin to show certain locations.
For the pin of each location I would like to show a url along with the label and address, so the user can click the url and open an info page.

I have created a custom pin to include the url, but I don't know how to show this on the pin.

Anyone know how to do this?

```
public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
    {
        public List<CustomPin> CustomPins { get; set; }

        public MapPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PlotPositions();
            MyMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(lat, long), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
        }

        public  void PlotPositions()
        {
            var myPos = new Position(lat, long);
            var pin = new CustomPin
            {
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = myPos,
                Label = "Glasgow City Centre",
                Address = "Argle Street, Glasgow",
                Url = "testUrl"
            };
            MyMap.Pins.Add(pin);
        }

        public class CustomPin : Pin
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Url { get; set; }
        }
```

}

```
internal class CustomPin
    {
        public PinType Type { get; set; }
        public Position Position { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

map page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             x:Class="gl_mobile_app.Views.Map.MapPage">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="back" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <Grid BackgroundColor="Gray">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Padding="20,20,20,20">
                <maps:Map 
                x:Name="MyMap"
                IsShowingUser="True"
                MapType="Street"
            />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you prowide code of your renderers and MapPage layout

Or try to use this example
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin.

If you want to improve Pin, you need to create map renderer in droid project.

In this renderer you need to override CreateMarker method.

```
    protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
    {
        var marker = new MarkerOptions();
        marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
        marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
        marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
        marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.Pin));
        return marker;
    }
```

You will need also Pin image for this marker.

In link that I posted above you can see example of method CreateMarker

Comment: I've updated the post to include the map page, I have no custom renderer yet for the map page as I'm not sure how to handle this.  As it is at the moment, the map does appear and pins are displayed.

Comment: First of all. Did you create api key for using google map?

Comment: Yes, that's all taken care of, the map works, I just don't know how to show the url with the pin

Comment: I edit my answer, check it. Look Xamarin Forms  good until you dont need customize something. Otherwise you need write platform specific code

Comment: thanks for all this - should that override be within the map page code behind, where the pins are created?

Comment: No, It must be in droid project. You need to check how rederers works. In two words renderer just replays you control on the view